# Using a subscript operator on a char pointer passed into a function doesn't modify the value. Why?

Tags: c++, dereference, subscript

I've noticed that the following function:

```
void myFunction(char *myString)
{
   myString[0] = 'H';
}
```

will not actually modify myString.  However, this function does:

```
void myFunction2 (char *myString)
{
   *myString = 'H';
}
```

It's obvious to me why myFunction2 works, though I'm not sure why myFunction does not work.  Could you explain this?

UPDATE:
No wait.  It works fine.  I'm dumb.  Can I delete this thing?

Comment: I'm not sure why either. Can you show how you call these functions by chance?

Comment: Both functions are identical so you shouldn't be seeing what you are seeing. How are you testing this?

Comment: I don't know what I've been smoking.  Just tried this and it works.  Errrr can't delete the question...stuck in an awkward state...

Comment: @CaseyPatton - I've decided that "too localized" is an acceptable reason to close the question, and you can vote to close yourself since it's your question if you feel it's not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you're right about that one. If you enter the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void fn1 (char *s) { *s = 'a'; }
void fn2 (char *s) { s[0] = 'a'; }

int main (void) {
    char str1[] = "hello";
    char str2[] = "goodbye";

    fn1 (str1); std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    fn2 (str2); std::cout << str2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

you'll find that both functions modify their data just fine, producing:

```
aello
aoodbye
```

So, if you're actually seeing what you say you're seeing, and I have no real reason to doubt you other than my own vast experience :-), the problem lies elsewhere.

In which case you need to give us the smallest complete program which exhibits the errant behaviour.

Comment: or pass pointers by ref (p*&) and problem solved